# Is it possible to limit bandwidth for transfers to Amazon S3 with Rusoto?

Tags: amazon-s3, rust

I am trying to manage and limit the bandwidth for the transfers from Amazon S3.

Are there any available options?

Comment: This feels like it should be a feature request of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a ticket to rusoto for this  issue.

[Reference](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto/issues/1083)